# iOS 11 Swift 4 Adding ChildViewController to UISCrollView doesn't take full height

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios11, childviewcontroller

I'm trying to make a snapchat like layout for my app.

I have a main viewcontroller with a scrollview. I add 3 viewcontrollers as children of the scrollview.

everything works fine on iOS 10 on a iPhone 5C but on iOS 11 on a iPhone 6S, the child view controller doesn't take the full height

[image]

The orange part is the child viewcontroller and the blue part is the scrollview

Here's my main VC code :

```
    let trendView = TrendViewController(nibName: "TrendViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let homeView = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let searchView = SearchViewController(nibName: "SearchViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)

    trendView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    homeView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    searchView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addChildViewController(trendView)
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(trendView.view)

    trendView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.addChildViewController(homeView)
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(homeView.view)
    homeView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.addChildViewController(searchView)
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(searchView.view)
    searchView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    var homeFrame = homeView.view.frame
    homeFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    homeView.view.frame = homeFrame

    var searchFrame = searchView.view.frame
    searchFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width * 2
    searchView.view.frame = searchFrame

    self.mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.height)
    self.mainScrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0)
```

I loaded an old project which has not the safe area in it and I don't have the problem ... don't know if there's a link with this problem

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I know i didn't assign any height but in all the examples i found, they never assigned an height to the child vc views.

I've just added these lines :

```
trendView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        trendView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        trendView.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        trendView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        homeView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trendView.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        homeView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        homeView.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        homeView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        searchView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: homeView.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        searchView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mainScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        searchView.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        searchView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

And now it works :)
Thanks